# Mac OSX | Tweak loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow

Tags: node.js, macos, authentication, electron

I am working on a project to my make my Mac Book Air pretty unique, currently it can modify displays and themes on the Mac, as well as the Apple Menu Bar is completely different and customized. Though I also want to tweak with the `Apple LoginWindow.app`, I want it to start an application connected to my network and the user can sign in by using the network authentication as well as two factor security pin codes on Android and IOS.

The path for this Application is located at:
`/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app`, now I don't know how to make my Node.js app run when the mac wakes up. **NOTE** I want my Application to replace Apple's login window app.

The app itself is finished, everything I need to do is to replace Apple's loginscreen with mine, but I don't know how to tweak loginwindow.app. Anyone knows? Thanks in advice!